# iOS simulator - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a problem here. My simulator works except the fact that it does not display the layout the way I want to. For example let's say that I put 8 buttons in a row  - same size - and then start the simulator. The simulator displays only 6 buttons,not the whole image. I scaled it to 50/100 but it did not fix my error. Any help? I am new to Xcode and I can't wait to start program apps for iOS.. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about Auto Layout and more specifically how to set constraints for different screen sizes. Before that, try running your project on different iOS Devices (simulator) to see the effect.

There is Ray's [Video Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64392/video-tutorial-beginning-auto-layout) on Auto Layout and the [Beginning Auto Layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) blog post for iOS 7. Maybe you give the rich Apple documentation a chance: [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1).

Comment: the tutorials seem very a very good starting point mate.thank you for your quick response.